# CarrierWave not saving image file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave

I am attempting to upload an image which is to be associated with every post via ImageUploader. However, after selecting the image file and hitting the upload button, no file url is being saved to the database. I have checked for the image url in the rails console and the image is not being saved. I find the post and see all of the other info associated with it and image:nil. I am also getting no error when the post creation form is submitted. However when the page is refreshed, the image selected and "saved" is gone. I have installed carrierwave, mini_magick, and fog correctly. Any ideas why the image is not being uploaded? Thanks everyone.

This is my code so far:

Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader


    default_scope { order('created_at DESC')}


  validates :title, length: {minimum: 5}, presence: true
  validates :body, length: {minimum: 20}, presence: true
  validates :topic, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true



  def markdown_title
    render_as_markdown(self.title)
  end

  def markdown_body
    render_as_markdown(self.body)
  end

  private 

  def render_as_markdown(markdown)
    renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new
    extensions = {fenced_code_block: true}
    redcarpet = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
    (redcarpet.render markdown).html_safe
  end

end
```

app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb upload path:

```
   def store_dir
     "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
   end
```

posts _form file:

```
<%= form_for [topic, post] do |f| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <h4>There are <%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
      <ul>
        <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:title]) do %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:body]) do %>
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area  :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post body" %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

posts/edit file:

```
 <h1>Edit Post</h1>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>Guidelines for posts</p>
     <ul>
       <li>Make sure it rhymes.</li>
       <li>Don't use the letter "A".</li>
       <li>The incessant use of hashtags will get you banned.</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post } %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

posts/show file:

```
<h1><%= @post.markdown_title %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <small>
      <%= image_tag(@post.user.avatar.tiny.url) if @post.user.avatar? %>
      submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago by
      <%= @post.user.name %>
    </small>
    <p><%= @post.markdown_body %></p>
    <small>
      <%= image_tag @post.image_url%> 
    </small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.new
    authorize @post
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user
    @post.topic = @topic
    authorize @post
      if @post.save
        flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
        redirect_to [@topic, @post]
      else
        flash[:error] = "There was an error saving this post. Please try again."
        render :new
      end
  end

  def edit
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize @post
  end

   def update
     @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     authorize @post
     if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
       flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
       redirect_to [@topic, @post]
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end
   end

   private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image)
  end

end
```

server log upon submitting form:

```
Started GET "/topics/1/posts/61/edit" for ::1 at 2015-08-02 21:49:54 -0400
Processing by PostsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"topic_id"=>"1", "id"=>"61"}
  Topic Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 61]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered posts/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (4.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 79ms (Views: 76.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started PATCH "/topics/1/posts/61" for ::1 at 2015-08-02 21:50:01 -0400
Processing by PostsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WrE4W30KlADBMbzSfNe/BCQPEHL3M4NhPGEo+Eop0iB9DA8QSHfz0zyBXsuW1NIHSyR7vFU1M7Ny4wUFMXO/Hg==", "post"=>{"title"=>"IMAGE IMAGE TESTING", "body"=>"JUST DO IT!!!!!! IMAGEEEEEEEE", "image"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save", "topic_id"=>"1", "id"=>"61"}
  Topic Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 61]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Topic Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Post Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 61]]
  SQL (23.1ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "image" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  [["image", nil], ["updated_at", "2015-08-03 01:50:01.161743"], ["id", 61]]
   (1.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/topics/1/posts/61
Completed 302 Found in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 25.0ms)


Started GET "/topics/1/posts/61" for ::1 at 2015-08-02 21:50:01 -0400
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"topic_id"=>"1", "id"=>"61"}
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 61]]
  Topic Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 73ms (Views: 71.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Comment: The image parameter was not passed. I assume it s name value on the file field is incorrect.

Comment: ahhhhhhh THANK YOU <%= f.hidden_field :image %> should have been <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>. Very, very sneaky

Comment: Where were you able to see that the image parameter was not passed?